# navigationBar root shows navigation Bar destination when slow left-edge swipe in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
             NavigationLink(destination: SecondCounter()){
                Text("Show Second Counter View")}
                .navigationBarTitle("RootView")
    }
}
struct SecondCounter : View {
    @State var timer: Timer? = nil
    @State private var secCounter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("")
            .navigationBarTitle("Second Counter View"      ,displayMode:.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:Text("\(secCounter)"))
            
            .onAppear {
                self.secondCounter()
            }
        .onDisappear {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.timer = nil
        }
    }
    func secondCounter () {
        timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.secCounter += 1
        })
    }
}
  struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider { 
      static var previews: some View {
             ContentView()
         }
     }
```

`why my destination view navigationBarTitle and NavigationBarItems(trailing) show on the root navigationBar when i do left-edge swipe in swiftui , I swipe the screen to the right, and see the root view, but my destination view items are now showing on my root navigationBar ?

if I do it fast, it goes to the root view without any problem, when I do it slow the problem occurs, oh and everything pass, the default back button, the title, and the trailing item when is there.
the navigationBarTitle string var I was using was not private , I make it private, and now the navigationBarTitle don't pass to the root view, when I am not using the timer. Now im fighting with a countodown timer I have as a navigationBarItems trailing, and that one is getting fuzzy, and all the bar appears on the root view.

The private var resolution was a false alarm, the counter is the problem, when I do the left-edge,i see more of the root vies, the counter immediately stops, and if I stays on the destination view then timer becomes blurry, and if I tap on < Back, the root view appears with the navigationBar of the destination view. If I go all the way to the right, the root view appears fine, without the destination view bar.
it only happens when the timer, the counter is working .

when I begin the left-edge s`enter code here`crolling, that I see the root view, the navigationBarItems(trailing), stop to upgrade the counter, but the timer continue working, (I print my var onBarRighTitle, and continue upgrading), when I stop the scrolling and stay in the destination view, the text receive again the output, and becomes blurry.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !!!!
I used the IOS 14 .toolbar, and is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the navigationBarTitle string var I was using was not private , I make it private, and now the navigationBarTitle don't pass to the root view, when I am not using the timer. Now im fighting with a countodown timer I have as a navigationBarItems trailing, and that one is getting  fuzzy, and all the bar appears on the root view.
thanks